# How to give user specific file access in gitlab?

Tags: permissions, gitlab

Is there any way to give user permissions for specfic files in a `GITLAB-Repository`? I want to give a user access to only one directory in my repository.

`GitLab Version:  8.1.3`

Comment: While it's a lot of hassle, you can may be able to accomplish what you want using [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) by allowing the user access to the child repo only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [protect a branch in GitLab](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/protected_branches.html), but not a full repo: if a user can see a repo, he/she can clone it all.

The easiest workaround would be to setup  a separate repo with only the content of that directory in it, for you to monitor and extract a patch whenever something changes in the folder:

```
git format-patch master --stdout > a_folder.patch
```

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that what you are asking for is not supported. You cannot grant user permissions for specific files in a git repository. In gitlab permissions are granted per repository.

Comment: This is a pity, is there any reason?

Comment: Sorry, I am not part of the gitlab developers team and it is pretty hard for me to answer your question about the reason for it. Your question would probably be better suited on the gitlab forums.